# Updating database table after changes to datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, sql-update

I've searched extensively about a simple approach to updating changes in a datagridview to a database using a stored procedure and thought that this approach was my answer. But I have a problem.

I have a project with a datasource called "testData" with a table from my database called "documents".

I have a windows form onto which I dragged the "documents" table, so documentsBindingSource and documentsTableAdaptor components were automatically added to my form. I added a datagridview and set it's datasource to documentsBindingSource; and an "Update" button with code-behind as below.

It all works fine, data is loaded at run time and I can make changes to the data in the datagridview.

However, when I click on the "Update" button, I get an error message indicating that
"(dgvDocumentName.DataSource as DataTable).Rows" (highlighted in code) " ... is not set to an instance of an object".

I would appreciate any guidance as to what I am doing wrong or what I have missed.

Thanks.

**Code-behind for "Update" button:**

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  dgvDocumentName.EndEdit();
  foreach (DataRow row in (dgvDocumentName.DataSource as DataTable).Rows)
  {
    if (row.RowState != DataRowState.Unchanged)
    {
      String sAction;

      switch (row.RowState)
      {
        case DataRowState.Added:
          sAction = "I";
          break;
        case DataRowState.Deleted:
          sAction = "D";
          break;
        case DataRowState.Modified:
          sAction = "U";
          break;
        default:
          sAction = "U";
          break;
      }
      documentsTableAdapter.procActionDocuments(Convert.ToInt32(row["colDocumentID"]),
                                                row["colDocumentName"].ToString(),
                                                Convert.ToInt32(row["colDocumentType"]),
                                                row["colDocumentText"].ToString(),
                                                sAction);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is (dgvDocumentName.DataSource as DataTable) the wrong cast? Check to make sure that is not null.

Comment: Hi Josh. Thanks for your reply. Yes the result of that cast is NULL, which is my problem. So what should I cast to allow me to perform this update. Any pointers/help would be great. Thanks, James

Comment: If you are using a debugger, you can check the type of dgvDocumentName.DataSource.

Comment: Thanks again Josh for your reply. I'm getting a bit thick as I get older I think. :) Of course the dgvDocumentName.DataSource was the binding source which I attached at design time.
I'm still left with what to do when user clicks "update" button.
I want to check each row in grid for changes (including whether it's a new record or just updated) so I can choose to discard a change if I need before calling the SP to do the work & also do data-conditional logic in the SP for each unique datarow. Do you have any suggestions about that approach? I'd be grateful for any ideas. Thanks, James

Comment: Can you post the code used to set up the binding? Is this WinForms?